# There is any way for implementing ttl on counter column in cassendra

Tags: cassandra

```
incr like_unlike_counter1234['b']['total']by 1 with ttl=10;
```

How to implement ttl in counter column .There is any way for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, counter columns don't support TTLs. See Jira issue [CASSANDRA-2103](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2103) for the technical details why this is tricky.